# How do I configure my Maven-war-plugin's useCache feature so that consecutive builds are faster?

Tags: maven, caching, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

I’m using Maven **3.3.0** on Mac Yosemite.  I wanted to make use of the maven-war-plugin’s `useCache` feature, but it isn’t doing anything in my multi-module project.  When I run

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

my project takes about 1:25 to run with the below configuration

```
<profile>
    <id>prepare-deploy-war-to-jboss</id>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useCache>true</useCache>
                    <cacheFile>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</cacheFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Then I run the same command again and the project takes the same amount of time.  I can see “work” files getting created so the plugin is definitely running but consecutive builds do not seem to be doing anything.

My question here isn’t so much as why isn’t `useCache` speeding up my build, but how can I configure my plugin differently so that consecutive runs do speed up the build?  If there is another plugin I should be using that would speed up builds on back-to-back runs, then that would also suffice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [WAR mojo code](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-war-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/war/AbstractWarMojo.java) (at the time of writing), the cache is mainly used by its [web app structure](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-war-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/war/util/WebappStructure.java) concerning [overlays management](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), so in most of the cases it would not improve build time indeed.

Moreover, as stated by [its official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#useCache), the cache mechanism is an **experimental** feature, hence disabled by default, which probably doesn't achieve (yet) user expectations.

---

Regardless of the effectiveness of this cache option, some hints to speed up maven builds could be:

- Consider whether you really need to `clean` at each and every run
- Consider building offline (`-o` option) if everything you need is already on your local cache
- Consider using threads during your build (`-T` option)
- Consider going on quite mode (`-q` option), swithing off build log temporarely and getting only error logs (basically: no news, good news)
- In your case, the War Plugin is activated upon the existence of a structure typical of a `war` packaging, which probably means this profile is part of the aggregator/parent pom and then activated only on the war module. Although it might impact very little, also consider moving the War Plugin configuration to its concerned module and avoid such a triggered configuration

---

Last but not least, during development time, build time is probably more important than war size, so you could switch off the **default** mechanism of re-compressing external libraries added to the war file, via the [`recompressZippedFiles`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#recompressZippedFiles) option:

> Indicates if zip archives (jar,zip etc) being added to the war should be compressed again. Compressing again can result in smaller archive size, but gives noticeably longer execution time.
>   **Default**: `true`

So a sample configuration would look like:

```
<properties>
    <war.recompress.files>false</war.recompress.files>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompressZippedFiles>${war.recompress.files}</recompressZippedFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: since there is no user property for this configuration entry, I also added a property for it, to switch it on/off on demand via command line (or via profile).

You could then test the different execution times executing the default build (with the configuration above disabling recompression) against the previous configuration (below, switching recompression on for the current execution, on demand):

```
mvn clean install -Dwar.recompress.files=true
```

You may then consider to [profile it](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to switch it on/off depending on development phase.

Comment: Hi, I switched to the option you recommended (chaginng the cacheFile to match yours) but still consecutive runs did nothing to improve speed.  I actually don't understand why that would do anything anyway.  The path is arbitrary.  Naming it "work" or "webapp-cache.xml" would not have any impact per my reading of the documentation.

Comment: @Dave my bad, I reviewed my answer with an hint to speed-up war creation, I tested and indeed it would slighly improve build time.

Comment: I appreciate the variety of options you offer.  I was tryihng all of them except, "recompressZippedFiles," which I didn't know about until I read your post.  However, sadly, I'm not noticing any significant difference between setting it true or false.  I will continue to play with this.